# Function to calculate median by column to an R dataframe that is done regularly to multiple dataframes

Tags: r, function, dataframe, mapply

Trying to write a function to combine multiple steps that are used regularly on an R dataframe.  At the moment I stack individual lines, which is most inefficient.  An Example each step I take at the moment

```
library(scores)
MscoreIndex <- 3


labMedians <- mapply(median, df[-1], na.rm = T) #calculate the median for each column except 1st
LabGrandMedian <- median(mapply(median, df[-1], na.rm = T),na.rm = T)
labMscore <- as.vector(round(abs(scores_na(labMedians, "mad")), digits = 2)) #calculate mscore by lab
labMscoreIndex <- which(labMscore > MscoreMax) #get the position in the vector that exceeds Mscoremax
df[-1][labMscoreIndex] <- NA # discharge values above threshold by making NA
```

An example my df below

```
structure(list(Determination_No = 1:6, `2` = c(55.94, 55.7, 56.59, 
56.5, 55.98, 55.93), `3` = c(56.83, 56.54, 56.18, 56.5, 56.51, 
56.34), `4` = c(56.39, 56.43, 56.53, 56.31, 56.47, 56.35), `5` = c(56.32, 
56.29, 56.31, 56.32, 56.39, 56.32), `7` = c(56.48, 56.4, 56.54, 
56.43, 56.73, 56.62), `8` = c(56.382, 56.258, 56.442, 56.258, 
56.532, 56.264), `10` = c(56.3, 56.5, 56.2, 56.5, 56.7, 56.5), 
    `12` = c(56.11, 56.46, 56.1, 56.35, 56.36, 56.37)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I started by trying to get the indivdual lab medians and the grandmedian with the following but got errors

I tried.

```
mediansFunction <- function(x){
              analytemedians <- mapply(median(x[,-1]))
              grandmedian <- median(x[,-1])
              list(analytemedians,grandmedian)
            }

mediansFunction(df)
```

But I get "Error in median.default(x[, -1]) : need numeric data"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
mediansFunction <- function(x){
  analytemedians <- sapply(x[-1], median)
  median_of_median <- median(analytemedians)
  grand_median <- median(as.matrix(x[-1]))
  
  list(analytemedians = analytemedians,
       median_of_median = median_of_median,
       grand_median = grand_median)
}

mediansFunction(df)

#$analytemedians
#     2      3      4      5      7      8     10     12 
#55.960 56.505 56.410 56.320 56.510 56.323 56.500 56.355 

#$median_of_median
#[1] 56.3825

#$grand_median
#[1] 56.386
```

Comment: thanks for the solution.  A few followup questions why did mapply not work this time, can I make the output a dataframe instead of a list and can i send items to the global environment without using return or list and within the function?

Comment: 1. `mapply` would work if you do `analytemedians <- mapply(median, x[-1], na.rm = T)`. In your code you are doing `analytemedians <- mapply(median(x[,-1]))` which is different. 2. How would your output dataframe look? Can you show with the help of this example? 3. You can but you should not, you should assign the output from the function to the variable like this `result <- mediansFunction(df)`

Comment: I have a follow up question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67252056/output-selected-variables-to-global-environment-r-function